# Username and password validation

Tags: php

I doing simple log in system. Username and passwords are saved in txt file (array format).
When I m log in I got "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded". here is my code. Thank for any hint.

```
   $clean = array();

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $user = isset($_POST['username']);
    $pass = isset($_POST['password']);


    $toread = fopen('filewriting.txt','r'); 

    while(!feof($toread))
    {
    $username = isset($clean['username']);
    $password = isset($clean['password']);
    }

    if($user == $username && $pass == $password)
    {

    $_SESSION['sess_user']=$user;

    /* Redirect browser */
    header("Location: page2.php");
    }
    } else {
    echo "Invalid username or password!";
    }

} else {
    echo "All fields are required!";
}
```

Comment: show the content as well the format saved in the file

Comment: Let's start with the fact that you're using isset wrong. Isset returns a boolean value so it's either true or false. You are using it as if it would give you the username and password...

Comment: Array
(
    [fullname] => David Bole
    [email] => bole@gmail.com
    [username] => bole
    [password] => 1234
)

Comment: Sidenote: Curious, Is this for personal use or a serious online site?

Comment: [***Do not store user credentials in plaintext***](http://bit.ly/XAbdKU). Do you want to end up [here](http://plaintextoffenders.com/)?

Comment: Microsoft; I see. Microsoft "what"?

Answer (score 1):

The below lines are not correct

```
$user = isset($_POST['username']);
$pass = isset($_POST['password']);
```

isset() returns true or false and hence the variables will be set to true or false

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

You have same

```
$username = isset($clean['username']);
$password = isset($clean['password']);
```

And values of `$user` and `$pass` is setting as true or false in all cases and further down the line its failing. Correct these first.